# How to fix broken encoding in Wine application without changing OS language?

Tags: keyboard, wine, language-support, encoding, system-language

The application I am talking about is Worms Armageddon (WA). I'm running it under wine.

Consider the following sequence:

- switch Ubuntu GUI language to Russian (and restart session)
- switch Ubuntu keyboard layout to Russian
- run WA under wine
- type something Cyrillic in WA chat

-- When I do so, I have no problems with encoding. But if I switch Ubuntu GUI language back to English (and restart session), then when typing Cyrillic characters in chat (using Russian keyboard layout), I get question marks (????, ? ?????!..) in chat instead of Cyrillic).

I guess it is somehow related to Windows code page. In Russian, the default code page is cp1251, and in English is probably some other European code page.

So my question is: how do I type and read Cyrillic in WA chat without switching GUI language to Russian?

P.S. The initial desktop icon is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Worms Armageddon
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/uname/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/uname/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/Worms\\ Armageddon.lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/uname/.wine/dosdevices/c:/GOG Games/Worms Armageddon/
Icon=4948_goggame-1462173886.0
StartupWMClass=wa.exe
```

and the `Worms Armageddon.lnk` is a Windows .lnk file referring to

```
C:\GOG Games\Worms Armageddon\WA.exe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the command line:

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 WINEPREFIX="/home/uname/.wine" wine /home/uname/.wine/drive_c/GOG\ Games/Worms\ Armageddon/WA.exe
```

Env variables set in start of command line affect only that command line. You could set it in separate line using `export LANG=...` but this will affect all commands in that shell after the export.

Second, a .desktop shortcut:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Worms Armageddon
Exec=env LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 env WINEPREFIX="/home/uname/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/uname/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/Worms\\ Armageddon.lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/uname/.wine/dosdevices/c:/GOG Games/Worms Armageddon/
Icon=4948_goggame-1462173886.0
StartupWMClass=wa.exe
```

Place above worms.desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/`
Note, you used default wine prefix, specifying it in command line not needed

May be you want it in script, here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
export WINEPREFIX="/home/uname/.wine"
wine /home/uname/.wine/drive_c/GOG\ Games/Worms\ Armageddon/WA.exe
```

export variable will have effect only inside that script

[Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Launching_desktop_application_with_an_environment_variable)